# Java scaled pixels?

Tags: java, android, scale, pixel

I'm doing a 2D game on android, and everything works just fine. The problem is the character moves really fast on my phone (Xperia) but on a phone with a much more wider screen he runs really slow. I tried getting the screen width and divide by 100 and set it as the step so the character will have a step depending on the width- didn't work. 
Is there some way to get some sort of scaled pixel or something. Appreciate the help :)

here's who i do it:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply your step width with `displaymetrics.density`. That effectively turns a "px" value into a "dp" value, i.e. it should be the same physical width on all devices.

Comment: Curious to know how this works perfectly though. Don't screens have different height and width even according to dp? Say, on a small screen to run across the width, it would take the character a certain amount of time *x*. On a large screen, it would take more time even if you used dp, because the width is not the same in dp on small and large screens .. right? Or am I missing something. Thanks.

Comment: The physical distance will be the same, no matter what size your screen has. If your sprite is 1 cm² and moves one cm per second, it will do so on all devices. You can completely ignore pixels. It will have a bigger playing field on larger devices, though (or a larger view of it).

Comment: So how would you maintain a constant sized playing field? Is that even possible with the huge array of screen sizes and densities without changing the game to fit each and every different type?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
int height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
int width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the density scale according to the default of 160, it is a multiplier and when you obtain the height and width in pixels you can use this multiplier in your code to correctly scale.

See the density section of the developer page linked below.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density